# mysqli querying 2 tables, but retrieve only results not in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there any way to make a single query statement?

```
left_table
id|group_id|member_id 
---------------------------------
1|10|100      
2|13|100
3|14|100
4|13|103
5|14|102

right_table
id|user_id|group_name 
-----------------------------------------
10|100|hundred  
11|101|hundredone
12|102|hundredtwo
13|103|hundredthree 
14|104|hundredfour

$query_id = 100
$results = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM right_table rt, left_table lt WHERE rt.user_id != '$query_id' and rt.id = lt.group_id and
lt.member_id != '$query_id'");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $r['group_name'].'<br>';

}
```

When i query both the table, i only want to retrieve the group name from right table 
where my $query_id is not in the left_table(member_id)

desire output for user_id 100 would be hundredone and hundredtwo because the member_id 100 is not part of
any 11 and 12 group from the right_table

Comment: Can you please post the results that you do get? Also, you won't get 'hundredone' because that row has an id of 101. Your condition says rt.id = lt.group_id. For 'hundredone' the id is 11 and there is no group_id 11 in the left table.

Comment: current result are hundred, hundredthree, hundredfour

Comment: yes precisely i want to get hundredone, is there anyway can i get the hundredone without the hundredone id on the left_table?

Comment: By having rt.id = lt.group_id in your WHERE condition, you are _requiring_ that the right table's id be in the left table's group_id column. If I am understanding you properly, you are only looking for those rows where the right table's id is _not_ in the left table's group_id column. So, consider using rt.id != lt.group_id.

Comment: yeah, i am looking for data not in the left_table! FuzzyTree codes solved my problem! Thanks for the help too, greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT group_name
FROM right_table rt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM left_table lt
    WHERE lt.member_id = 100
    AND lt.group_id = rt.id
)
```